# Dynamic content from a backing bean not being updated immediately in the view

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces

I am working on a Java EE application where the user can register some units. I want that each unit to be displayed on a separated tab when the user is logged in.

```
<p:tabView id="unitTabs" cache="false" var="unit" value="#{getUnitsOfLoggedInUser(loginController.checkedUser)}"> 
        <p:tab id="unitTab" title="#{unit.unitName}">  

            //content here

        </p:tab>  
</p:tabView>
```

In the backing bean I have this method

```
public List<Unit> getUnitsOfLoggedInUser(User user) {
    unitsOfLoggedInUser = (List<Unit>) user.getUnitCollection();
    return unitsOfLoggedInUser;
}
```

However, if the user creates a new unit, the new tab will not be rendered immediately. Even if I refresh the page, it still is not displayed. However, if I restart the server and run again, the new tab will be there. It seems that it has some caching property and does not load on each call.

Also, when I debug the code the method `getUnitsOfLoggedInUser(user)` is called more than one time before the page is rendered.

I have also tried with a JSF data table but it behaves the same, so it is not a problem of the Primefaces library

Does anyone have any suggestion how can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the way you save new units. One option is to refresh the `user` entity after saving a new unit. In any case you could do

```
em.refresh(user);
```

after saving, where `em` is your instance of the `EntityManager`.

Update:

You could also add the new unit to the collection of the user and then merge/edit the user instead of directly creating the new unit. Then you wouldn't need to refresh the user because you manually added the unit to the collection.

Comment: I added what you said to the method `create` to the EJB. But I receive the exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not refresh not managed object: class web.effectinet.entities.User.` I am using netbeans generated code for the EJBs so I overwrote the method create in the `UnitFacade` EJB

Comment: That is as expected. In the create method for the unit, no user is managed. It is difficult to tell without knowing your entities and their relations. If you have a 1:n relation of user and units you could also add the new unit to the collection of the user and then merge/edit the user instead of directly creating the new unit. Then you wouldn't need to refresh the user because you manually added the unit to the collection.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to do it by modifying the unitCollection attribute of the user object manually when a unit is created. However, I wanted to ask something out of curiosity. Before, I tried to create a refresh(User user) method in the User EJB. However when calling this from the managed bean I received the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not refresh not managed object for [userId = 31]` which was the logged in user for the moment. I am not being able to understand why this was not working. Anyways thanks again

Comment: The logged in user is not managed automatically. *Managed* means that an entity is part of a persistence context. If you are using EJBs generated by Netbeans the persistence context lives as long as the EJB method runs (transaction scoped persistence context). The entities persisted by these "Netbeans"-EJBs are by default not managed after the  `create(..)` method exits.